# A small bug when closing questions

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

Normal steps that is not buggy:

- Vote to close
- Choose `off-topic because...`
- Choose other
- Click on another reason
- Result: `Vote to close` is not disabled

Steps to reproduce buggy behavior:

- Vote to close
- Choose `off-topic because...`
- Choose other
- **Add a space to the custom reason**
- Click on another reason
- Result: `Vote to close` button **continues to stay disabled**

Expected behavior:

Whatever it says in the custom close reason, if another option gets selected, the Vote to close button should not be disabled.

[image: Vote to close button is disabled]

Comment: I can only seem to repro it for the top reason here on Meta. Not for all of them.

Comment: It only seems to happen for me on the first different off-topic reason I choose besides other, once adding the space. Once I keep clicking, the button is appropriately enabled again. Still incorrect behavior, of course.

Comment: Also, incidentally, I don't need to type a space in the Other -> Comment box to see this behavior.

Comment: I got the button to blink also when playing around a little with the close reason checkboxes. Not quite sure how to reproduce this blinking though, this feels like a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)

Comment: Heisenbugs are frustrating, but not as bad as [Hindenburgs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster) ;>

Comment: @AndrewBarber Watch your greengrocer's apostrophes, please.

Comment: @michaelb958 Egads! I hate it when people do that! (Fixed! ;)

Comment: Although I agree that this question is a duplicate, none of the other questions actually **has a real answer**, or a comment from the StackExchange development team.